# Execute sh file from Java

Tags: java, linux, sh, execute, gnu-screen

I am trying to execute an sh file via the following code (CentOS machine btw)

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh " + file.getPath());
```

I use this code for windows and it works fine

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start " + file.getPath());
```

Could it be because I'm using Screen in the .sh file? I am also using the java command to start the server so maybe I need to include these?

Here are the contents of the sh file

```
#!/bin/sh
BINDIR=$(dirname "$(readlink -fn "$0")")
cd "$BINDIR"
screen -S PrivateServer java -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -jar somejar.jar -o true
```

I am also running this code from a shutdown hook, could this be the issue? This is intended because the software is a game server and it is intended so that the user can use a restart command or have it auto restart without needing to setup anything them self.

Edit: I decided to output the errors to a text file and found this "Must be connected to a terminal." any ideas? I believe this is an issue to do with using screen.

Comment: Are you sure your file is executable (e.g. `chmod +x filename`)? Also, consider using `getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"sh",file.getPath()});`

Comment: Perhaps the shell isn't parsing your command line properly. What's the value of `file.getPath()`? Check that the file is being run with a suitable environment (path, etc.) Try a simple sh file (e.g., one that just logs that it ran).

Comment: @iTech Yes the file is executable as I am executing it from the console

Comment: @TedHopp Will do, could this be anything to do with the fact that I am running this in a shutdown hook? It's meant to launch another program that will stay open until terminated. This is intended as a server command so that the user can restart the server via a command.

Comment: @iTech I finally found the error, decided to get it to output to an error log and found this "Must be connected to a terminal." So how can I fix this?

Comment: try to add `-t` to the `sh` command http://serverfault.com/questions/21806/how-can-i-launch-a-screen-session-with-a-command-over-ssh-on-a-remote-server-fro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you confirmed that the file has executable permission, try to pass the argument as follows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh" ,"-c", file.getPath()});
```

So mainly provide the complete path for `sh` and use `-c`

Comment: It seems to be working if in the script I just simply create a directory but it doesn't seem to like the screen command, maybe I need to include or use the exact location of screen?

Comment: I finally found the error, decided to get it to output to an error log and found this "Must be connected to a terminal." So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to set the permissions for the operation, usually the "sh" files require execution permission in order to run this scripts from a Java Application. You must run the Java application as root (sudo su) or sudo java -jar. Or set full access to your script "sudo chmod 777 ..." well, not full access, but at least chmod +x for any user that wants to execute your script.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using org.apache.commons.exec.* to run such.

Comment: Do you have any example code? I can't seem to find much documentation

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to have executable permissions, try executing `"chmod +x shell_script_filename"` before executing the shell script